# Ember JS: Computed Property returning NaN

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a computed property that is not being recalculated and gets stuck when the page is first displayed.

```
totalSpeed: function() {
    return this.get('job') ? parseInt(this.get('job').get('speed')) + parseInt(this.get('speed')) : parseInt(this.get('speed'));
}.property('job','job.speed','speed'),
```

Speed as defined in my object

```
speed: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0}),
```

Speed as defined in my job object

```
speed: DS.attr('number'),
```

I can output both the job's speed and my object's speed separately and they display fine. If I try to output my totalSpeed property I get NaN. If I change either job.speed or speed, totalSpeed will update and show correctly.

Does anyone know why on the initial load totalSpeed does not display?
If I log the values that totalSpeed returns I get for example if speed is 8 and job.speed is 8
NaN
16
16

Comment: It seems like this.get('speed') is returning undefined inside your computed property when the page loads. I have a couple inklings as to why this might be (maybe defaultValue 0 is not doing what you think it's doing?), but it's hard to know without seeing more of the code. Can you make a jsfiddle with the behavior? http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/

Comment: Pretty straightforward bug... `parseInt` returns NaN when the result is not a number. Try changing `this.get('job').get('speed')` to `this.get('job.speed')`. If that doesn't work, put a breakpoint in there and inspect the properties to see what's going on. You are possibly working with an async relationship that hasn't loaded.

Comment: Could you clarify "I get for example if speed is 8 and job.speed is 8 NaN 16 16"? If `speed` is 8 and `job.speed` is 8 you get NaN? What is the "16 16" part?

Answer (score 0):

Matt I think you are correct about the relationship not loading , I was kind of being a bit hacky with the way I was loading my model(multiple models in one controller). I ended up using a Em.RSVP.hash and everything works fine.

What I had

```
App.CharacterEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    authRedirectable: true,
    model: function(model) {
        var auth = this.container.lookup('auth:main');
        return this.get('store').find('user',auth.get('userId'));
    },
    setupController : function(controller, model){
        controller.set("model", model.get('profile').get('currentCharacter'));
        controller.set('races',this.get('store').findAll('race'));
        controller.set('jobs',this.get('store').findAll('job'));
    }

});
```

What I now have

```
App.CharacterEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    authRedirectable: true,
    model: function(model) {
        var auth = this.container.lookup('auth:main');
        return Em.RSVP.hash({
            user: auth.get('user'),
            races: this.get('store').findAll('race'),
            jobs: this.get('store').findAll('job')
        });
    },
    setupController : function(controller, model){
        controller.set('model',model);
    }

});
```